# command output in an array in sh shell

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am trying to take output of an command into array and for this tried following:

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd=($(date +%s;sleep 5; date +%s))
start_time=$cmd[0]
end_time=$cmd[1]
echo $start_time

#EOF
```

I was expection echo $start_time to give me start time but it print the following:

1572443382 1572443386[0]

Can't switch to bash shell and have only access to sh

Comment: But what I would like to have output to be stored in array for both date commands and for some reasons bash/ksh can't be used.

Comment: Since you cannot use bash please don't tag the question as bash. I removed the tag for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positional parameters are the closest thing `sh` has to an array:

```sh
sh-3.2$ set -- "$(date +%s)"; sleep 5; set -- "$@" "$(date +%s)"
sh-3.2$ start=$1 end=$2; echo "$start -> $end"
1572448562 -> 1572448567
```

Comment: Good idea! In this case you can assign both parameters in one command just how OP wanted: `set -- $(date +%s; sleep 5; date +%s); echo "$1 -> $2"`. Your solution can even be used without mangling the original positional parameters: `set -- $(...) "$@"; ...; shift 2 # everything is back to normal`.

Answer (score 5):

Plain `sh` has no arrays. You have to cope without arrays. In your case that's easy:

```
start=$(date +%s)
sleep 5
end=$(date +%s)

echo "start=$start end=$end"
```

If you really, really want to have everything in one subshell then you have to store the output as a plain string and parse that string to retrieve the individual values. You can think of that one string as an "array" where each line is an array entry. Individual lines can be retrieved using `sed` (which uses indices starting from 1 instead of 0).

```
times=$(date +%s; sleep 5; date +%s)

echo "start=$(echo "$times" | sed -n 1p) end=$(echo "$times" | sed -n 2p)"
```

To store individual lines in variables use subshells:

```
times=$(date +%s; sleep 5; date +%s)
start=$(echo "$times" | sed -n 1p)
end=$(echo "$times" | sed -n 2p)

echo "start=$start end=$end"
```

However, if you just want to compute how long `sleep 5` took you might as well use `time sleep 5` which already does that for you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use ${array[index]} syntax to access array elements. So, change your `start_time` and `end_time` to as follows.

```
start_time=${cmd[0]}
end_time=${cmd[1]}
```

Also change

`#!/bin/sh`
to
`#!/bin/bash`

Comment: I mentioned in the comments, I can't use bash for some reason, all I can use is sh

Comment: Yes, if `/bin/sh` is actually a link to a shell that supports arrays, which by definition is something you can't rely on. Not all Linux distributions use `bash` as its POSIX-compliant shell.